# Change a container postion in react-native

Tags: flexbox, react-native, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I was trying to customize jitsi-meet. Here toolbar contains video mute, audio mute, and other buttons. How to place the container with blue background in the bottom of the screen?
If I remove `height` property then this whole thing is placed in the bottom of the screen but in this case I don't get spacing around items in toolbar.

```js
toolbar: {
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        marginBottom: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
        height: '70%',
    },
```

If I put `height:'100%'` it takes whole screen. Other elements are commented here. This screen in stacked top of a camera screen.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post your full code of what you're rendering? Or is 'toolbar' the only object on the page?

Comment: @RossHochwert can you please edited post.

Comment: You did not add the full code of what you're rendering, so it's hard for me to understand. My recommendation is to put a `View` around your toolbar, and set the `justifyContent` to `flex-end` to start at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
toolbar: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        marginBottom: 10,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        width:'100%',
        backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
    }
```

if you want to align the content in a horizontal row then you should give the flexDirection='row'. In react native default flexDirection is column so there is no need to mention it explicitly.

Comment: I want to keep elements in toolbar stacked.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand without posting what you're fully rendering, but it seems like you need to wrap the toolbar view in a parent view, and fix the parent view to start at the bottom of the page through `justifyContent: 'flex-end'`

```
<View style={{justifyContent:'flex-end', flex:1}}>
  <View style={{styles.toolbar}}>
  </View>
</View>
```

Alternatively, you could set the parent view to `flexDirection: 'column-reverse'`.